# Setting for automatically scaling parentheses in math mode

Tags: math-mode, equations, align, amsmath

Is it possible in LaTeX, that parentheses scale automatically? When I have a fraction for example I don't want these parentheses to be so small:

[image]

I know I can use `\left(` and `\right)` to get it the way I want, but I'm annoyed of always typing that. I never want parentheses not to cover what's inside. Is there any way to tell latex to always use `\left(` / scale automatically and instead manually type whenever I want the default way?

Comment: You really should not be using autoscalling fences. They often end up being too tall (example `\[ \left(\sum_i \\right)\]`, so it is better to add `\left...\right` only when actually needed.

Comment: this is not possible in any reasonable way without breaking other code (and it usually is not desirable as `\left(\right)` makes sub-optimal spacing if used when not needed. I'm sure the question must be a duplicate, I'll see if I can find.....